# How can I find a [cosmology] question where I cannot remember any text or title for a search?

Tags: support, search

I answered a question and I have saved a copy of the text from my answer. Is there a way I can search for this?

ADDED

I should have added this a while ago, but I forgot about it after I went through the list of all my answers again and found what I was looking for.  My thanks to all the commenters.

Comment: What have you tried to enter into the search bar so far that hasn't worked? And is there a reason you can't get to the question from the link to the answer in your profile?

Comment: I tried: "[cosmology] answers:1".  I also tried the same with the following answer test included: "What is the theoretical expected value of the CMB's watts".  I also looked at the list of 19 questions I have answered, but I could not find he one I was looking for. Is it possible the question (and answer and comments) was deleted?

Comment: You don't have any deleted answers... So if you looked through the 19 answers linked in your profile and it isn't there, then I'm not sure... I just manually looked at all deleted [tag:cosmology] questions from the past 30 days and there aren't any answers on any of them.

Comment: Are you sure it actually had the cosmology tag?  Could it have been a cosmology question without the tag, or a question where that tag was removed?

Comment: Hi JMac:  At this point I have to believe that anything might have happened. However, I had thought that I needed  to include in a search at lease one tag, and [cosmology] has been the only tag I have been using.

Comment: @Buzz You don't need to include a tag at all, you can search without it. But tags help focus the search certainly. However, since you don't have any deleted answers attached to your profile, it seems your answer was not posted (so searching using the words from your answer won't work). But, it might still be saved in the entry box on the question if you can find it again. The next best option is to go through your browser history for the time frame in question and visit the potential questions to see if its there.

Comment: Some [search engines are quite good at searching for (exact) phrases](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/144207/google-for-the-exact-phrase-and-no-quotation-marks-dont-help).

Answer (score 1):

I just looked through your list of all answers and found [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/587648/23473) within a minute. It seems like what you are looking for. Nice to meet a fellow cosmology buff. Makes me feel less bad about my recent inactivity. Keep up the good work and I'm sure you'll surpass me in answer record one day.